# create a jquery sliderbar in ember js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple jquery slider bar but am having no luck.  I've looked at many questions that looked relevant on here and other sites but nothing seems to work.  I have changed the code around a few times but currently I have this.

```
App.SliderView = Ember.View.extend({
      didInsertElement: function() {
         this.$().slider({
             range: "min",
             value: 50,
             min: 1, 
             max: 100
         });
     } 
  });

{{#view App.SliderView}}
    {{/view}}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : https://github.com/RVenkatesh/Ember-slider . This library built using Ember Views. It enables you to include different types of sliders in any Ember view.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this does not work for you, because you are using the block form of the view helper. To make your example work, you would have to use:

```
{{view App.SliderView}}
```

But to encourage more flexibility you should go for something like:

```
App.SliderView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName : "slider",
    elementSelector : ".slider",
    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$(this.get("elementSelector")).slider({
         range: "min",
         value: 50,
         min: 1, 
         max: 100
        });
    } 
});
```

And the corresponding template:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

This would enable you to easily add additional markup to your slider, when needed. You could even extend this approach further and make the properties for the slider part of your view.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I.e. why doesn't the OP's code work in block form with no div inside?

Comment: If you use the block form `{{#view App.SliderView}}{{/view}}` Ember does not insert a DOM element at all. And therefore the call `this.$()` should not work, since there is no element. My proposal however will insert a div element. It is described in the docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view **I admit that this might be confusing, but it seems awkward to use the block form without specifying a template.**

Comment: I read through the docs you linked to. It doesn't say anything about not creating a DOM element.

Comment: The first example shows it: `A span:
{{#view tagName="span"}}
  hello.
{{/view}}` results in `<div class="ember-view">
    A span:
    <span id="ember1" class="ember-view">
      Hello.
    </span>
  </div>
</body>`. There is no separate div for the view block.

Comment: No, there's a span, which [defaults to div if tagName is not specified](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0/packages/ember-views/lib/views/view.js#L1856).

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I have overseen that earlier. Hmm then i am unsure, why this did not work. One would a fiddle to dive in deeper.

Comment: Sorry for this very late response.  Your answer sadly didn't fix my problem.  Not sure how to explain it, because I don't understand it exactly myself but I it seemed to me that the slider wasn't loading with the dom.  I'm also using ersi api.  Out of a "what the hell why not thought" I put my slider code within the function that was setting points on my map, which only gets called when the slider is needed, and it worked!  Seems like the slider was trying to load too fast.  Green's post was closer to what my actual code looked like.  Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: If you have the feeling that your Slider was loading too fast, checkout my blog post for a possible explanation. http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/

Comment: awesome post, I'll have to try and implement that logic into my service instead of what I did.  Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting in a div for the slider to hook onto.  So your template would be :

```
{{#view App.SliderView}}
  <div class="sliderDiv"></div>
{{/view}}
```

And then in `didInsertElement` you'd call:

```
this.$('.sliderDiv').slider({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just using ember-slider, if you are using ember-cli: https://github.com/yinaw/ember-slider